# Align equations horizontally with related vertical cells

Tags: tables, math-mode, align

I have a table like this:

```latex
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Etumerkillinen}} \\
    \hline
    Tyyppi & Minimi & Maksimi \\
    \hline
    i8   & $ -2^{7}   $ & $ 2^{7}-1   $\\
    i16  & $ -2^{15}  $ & $ 2^{15}-1  $\\
    i32  & $ -2^{31}  $ & $ 2^{31}-1  $\\
    i64  & $ -2^{64}  $ & $ 2^{63}-1  $\\
    i128 & $ -2^{127} $ & $ 2^{127}-1 $\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

The table is rendered like this:

[image: Table rendering]
I would like to align the math equations in a way that the 2's, 1's and the negative signs are aligned horizontally in relation with each other. Is this possible and how would I achieve that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! If I understand well, you want the 2nb and 3rd columns cells to be internally left-aligned ang globally centred?

Comment: Be aware of the typo in the column `Minimi` the field `-2^{64}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you'll go wrong if you choose left-alignment for both data columns. To align the numbers in the second column on `2`, `-` and `1`, you could split the single column into three distinct sub-columns.

I would focus my efforts more on giving the table a more open "look", as is done on the right in the following screenshot.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} % for '\newcolumntype' macro
\newcolumntype{L}{>{$}l<{$}}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{${}}c<{{}$}}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|L|L@{}C@{}L|} 
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{5}{|c|}{\textbf{Etumerkillinen}} \\
    \hline
    Tyyppi & $Minimi$ & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Maksimi} \\
    \hline
    i8   &  -2^{7^{\mathstrut}}    &  2^{7} & - & 1   \\
    i16  &  -2^{15}   &  2^{15} & - & 1  \\
    i32  &  -2^{31}   &  2^{31} & - & 1  \\
    i64  &  -2^{64}   &  2^{63} & - & 1  \\
    i128 &  -2^{127}  &  2^{127} & - & 1 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}%
\qquad
\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\kern2pt} l L L@{}C@{}L @{}} % cf barbara beeton's comments below
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{5}{c}{\textbf{Etumerkillinen}} \\
    \cmidrule{1-5}
    \multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Tyyppi} & $Minimi$ & \multicolumn{3}{c@{}}{Maksimi} \\
    \midrule
    i8   &  -2^{7}    &  2^{7}  & - & 1   \\
    i16  &  -2^{15}   &  2^{15} & - & 1  \\
    i32  &  -2^{31}   &  2^{31} & - & 1  \\
    i64  &  -2^{64}   &  2^{63} & - & 1  \\
    i128 &  -2^{127}  &  2^{127} & - & 1 \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: And the alignment of the `-` and `1` in the third column (as far as I understood OP would like to have this as well, probably easiest some extra columns for "inside" the third column).

Comment: @albert  - Good catch. Please see the revised answer.

Comment: Nit-pick.  In the right-hand image, the first column, beginning with "i", looks squished tightly up against the left edge, especially since the "T" in the column header has some "air" on the left and the "i" is so narrow that it almost looks cut off.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Good one. I suppose the squished look could be alleviated by changing `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{} l L L@{}C@{}L @{}}` to `\begin{tabular}[t]{@{\kern1pt} l L L@{}C@{}L @{}}` and `Tyyppi` to `\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{Tyyppi}`. :-)

Comment: Good plan.  I'd be tempted to indent the "i"s even a little more, maybe as much as 2pt.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - Interestingly, the squished look is present in the first column of the left-hand `tabular` environment as well. I suspect it's caused by an optical interaction (interference?) between the `T` in the header row and the multitude of somewhat puny-looking `i` characters in the next five rows.

Comment: It's true that it's an optical illusion, but it's more obvious in the table on the right because the rules delineating the table start at exactly the same place as the table contents.  The table on the left has a buffer.

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I went with your `\kern2pt` suggestion. :-)

Comment: Much better now!  The "i" still looks skinny, but that can't be helped (and it would be much worse in sans serif).

Comment: @barbarabeeton - I suppose that it also helps to have a bit of serendipitous symmetry between the whitespace padding to the left of the first column and to the right of the final column. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can define `\2` macro and use it:

```
\def\2^#1{\hbox to1.6em{$2^{#1}$\hss}}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|r|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Etumerkillinen}} \\
    \hline
    Tyyppi & Minimi & Maksimi \\
    \hline
    i8   & $ -\2^{7}   $ & $ \2^{7}-1   $\\
    i16  & $ -\2^{15}  $ & $ \2^{15}-1  $\\
    i32  & $ -\2^{31}  $ & $ \2^{31}-1  $\\
    i64  & $ -\2^{64}  $ & $ \2^{63}-1  $\\
    i128 & $ -\2^{127} $ & $ \2^{127}-1 $\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Please make a complete example out of it and show the output in an image.

Comment: I have made the example complete as as it is in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible layout, with the formulæ aligned and centred in their respective columns.  It requires `eqparbox` for the alignment, and `collcell` to use the former in tables:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array} %

\usepackage{eqparbox}
\newcommand{\eqmathboxM}[1]{\eqmakebox[M][l]{$#1$}}
\newcommand{\eqmathboxm}[1]{\eqmakebox[m][l]{$#1$}}
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt}
\begin{tabular}[t]{|l|>{\collectcell\eqmathboxm}c< {\endcollectcell}|>{\collectcell\eqmathboxM}c< {\endcollectcell}|}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{\textbf{Etumerkillinen}} \\
    \hline
    Tyyppi & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Maxi Minimi} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{Mini Maksimi} \\
    \hline
    i8 & -2^{7} & 2^{7}\hfill- 1 \\
    i16 & -2^{15} & 2^{15}\hfill -1 \\
    i32 & -2^{31} & 2^{31}\hfill - 1 \\
    i64 & -2^{64} & 2^{63}\hfill - 1 \\
    i128 & -2^{127} & \eqmakebox[M]{$ 2^{127}- 1 $} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]